# How can you figure out where an exception was thrown?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Suppose you have a code like that:

```
Random rnd=new Random();
try {

  if(rnd.nextInt(1000)==0) {
     throw new Exception();
  }
  // repeat above code N times, N being big.

}catch(Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error("caught:", e);
}
```

Now I add a breakpoint into the catch-clause. If it gets caugt, how can I figure out the line-number which throw the exception?

Comment: @R.J: It's not about the reputation. It's about sending a message.

Comment: The stack trace should indicate where it went wrong

Comment: Never throw `java.lang.Exception`.  Please.  Write your own specific one if you need to, but don't throw `Exception`.  Your coworkers may throw you after that.

Comment: @EricJablow still better than `Throwable`

Comment: @Woot4Moo: What about `class Ball extends Throwable{}` as in xkcd last week?

Comment: @EricJablow touche my friend.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace includes this information.

[ideone](http://ideone.com/EKu2U6):

stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: This is not always right, as the line numbers can be missing, depending on the compiler settings.

Comment: @Bananeweizen and for the sake of discussion which java compiler settings would those be?

Comment: Sorry for missing that: javac -g:none. Find more information by googling "java stacktrace unknown source", as "unknown source" is what you get instead of "Main.java:8" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception breakpoint:

In the exception dialog, press the "J!" button, then catch on the exception.

Here are screenshots:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-addexception_viewaction.htm

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the only working solution in all cases, including third party binary code without sources.

Comment: @Bananeweizen, he is answering his own question.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Self answering questions is allowed on stackoverflow and no reason for downvoting. The voting shall judge the content of the answer, not who posted it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score -2):

You already know the line number, it's the line with `throw new Exception()` in it ;)

If you mean that you want to know how many times you've gone round the loop, then you can include the loop counter in your constructor for the Exception, and get it out again with `e.getMessage()`

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  From reading the question, I understood that there was only line which could be throwing the exception (hence the stacktrace is useless for working out what went wrong), but that this line was executed several times - hence something a bit more meaningful than "new Exception()" should be thrown.